# jQuery append in loop - DOM does not update until the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When looping over a large collection and appending it to the DOM, the DOM only refreshes after all items have been appended. Why doesn't the DOM update after each `append()` call? Can I force the DOM to refresh after each append (or maybe after each n number of appends)?

```
var i = 0;
for (i=0; i<5000; i++) {
    $('#collection').append('<li>Line Item</li>');
}
```

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZG7f/)

NOTE: I understand that better performance (avoiding DOM reflow) can be achieved by appending all elements to a local variable, and then appending that variable to the DOM. But I want the first n elements to render on the screen, then the next n, etc. until all elements are rendered.

Comment: I think it does, but I think it freezes the UI while doing the big loop, so it appears that it did it all at once but it didn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most everything in the browser stops while a Javascript is running. This includes for example DOM rendering, event handling, image animation.

The only way to cause the DOM to be rendered is to end the Javascript. You can use the `setTimeout` method to start code again after the update:

```
var  i = 0;

function appendSomeItems() {
  for (var j=0; j<50; i++, j++) {
    $('#collection').append('<li>Line Item</li>');
  }
  if (i < 5000) window.setTimeout(appendSomeItems, 0);
}

appendSomeItems();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Uf4N6/

Answer (score 3):

you need to give back control to the browser every once in a while:

```
    var current = 0


    function draw() {
        var next = current + 10
        for(var i = current; i < next; i++) {
            $('#collection').append('<li>Line Item</li>');
        }
        current = next
        setTimeout(draw, 50);
    }

draw();
```

Answer (score -2):

Generally, please don't touch DOM too many times. It is a performance killer as you have already observed.

```
var result="";
for (i=0; i<5000; i++) {
    result+='<li>Line Item</li>';
}
$('#collection').append(result);
```

In this way, you touch DOM only once!

An alternative way is using array.

```
var result=[];
for (i=0; i<5000; i++) {
    result.push('<li>Line Item</li>');
}
$('#collection').append(result.join(""));
```

Comment: NOTE: I understand that better performance (avoiding DOM reflow) can be achieved by appending all elements to a local variable, and then appending that variable to the DOM. But I want the first n elements to render on the screen, then the next n, etc. until all elements are rendered.

Comment: O yes. Sorry I didn't address your need.

Answer (score -3):

If that's really what you want to do...

```
var i = 0;
for (i=0; i<5000; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#collection').append('<li>Line Item</li>');
    }, 0);
}
```