# JS function does not run until very end while inside FOR

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a for block that iterates a list of objects. Each object's name will be displayed in a div (#console).

When the code runs, console.log is output-ed in real time. However, it seems that the method that is supposed to append data to #console executes only after when the for block completes.

How do I make doSomething() run in real time as well?

```
for(var i = 0; i < objectList.length; i++)
{
    console.log(objectList[i]); //  this runs immediately
    doSomething(objectList[i]); //  this runs only AFTER the loop completes
}

function doSomething(obj)
{
    $("#console").append(obj.name);
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: its working, see an example here : https://jsfiddle.net/e6c4h8qd/
it's just console.log and its working expectedly.
Can you frame your question in a working demo on jsFiddle or Codepen ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: `this runs only AFTER the loop completes` - not so - the issue is page render timing

Comment: @ObsidianAge not likely relevant at all

Comment: Jaramonda X is right, the jsfiddle from Abhishek Kumar has removed the jQuery that appends to the DOM, so it's removed the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the render of a DOM update be a blocking function? Is jQuery doing something smart to delay/batch all the DOM manipulation?

Comment: I've added a `debug;` after `$("#console").append(obj.name);` and you can see it stops after the first loop and both outputs are there - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrdgWO

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058858/jquery-append-in-loop-dom-does-not-update-until-the-end

Answer (score 1):

Your code blocks the DOM from rendering until it finishes executing, which is why you see `#console` rendering only after the loop completes.

You could use `setTimeout` to let the DOM render, and do something like this:

```js
var objectList = [{name: 'hello'}, {name: 'world'}];

function loopThroughList() {
  var i = 0;
  var loop = function () {
     if (i >= objectList.length) {
       return;
     }
     console.log(objectList[i]);
     doSomething(objectList[i]);
     setTimeout(loop, 0);
     i++;
  };
  loop();
}

function doSomething(obj) {
     $("#console").append(obj.name);
}

loopThroughList();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="console"></div>
```

Note that this is a pretty slow loop, since setTimeout tends to actually timeout for 4ms+ per iteration.

Also see: [jQuery append in loop - DOM does not update until the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058858/jquery-append-in-loop-dom-does-not-update-until-the-end)